# I'm having trouble with this array, It keeps returning an out of bounds error, why?

Tags: java, arrays

```
 System.out.println("Please Enter the Size of your arrays");
       int arraysize = in.nextInt();
       //initalize array
       int [][] aOne = new int[arraysize][arraysize];
       int [][] aTwo = new int[arraysize][arraysize];
       int [][] aSum = new int[arraysize][arraysize];
       // load array 1  
      for (int i = 0; i< aOne.length; i++){
          for(int x = 0; i<aOne[i].length;x++){
              aOne[i][x] = ((int)(Math.random()*15));

          }

      }
```

The array above ... should work, no?   I cant figure out why i'm unable to fill it with Math.random.

any suggestions?

Comment: Your inner loop refers to `i`... `i < aOne[i].length` should be `x < aOne[i].length`...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an apparent typo.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - how would that make this off-topic?

Comment: Did you compile it your new code? It should work.

Comment: @admdrew If we still had the "too localized" option, I'd have voted for that, but we don't, so I wrote that particular reason.  The problem here is that this is relatively simple typo, and it's not anything that's so specific that anyone else who is having the same problem would be likely to find this question, or to benefit from it.  There's no canonical answer here except "make sure you're checking the right index variable in your `for` loops."

Comment: @admdrew For some discussion of this type of problem, see the MSO questions [How to flag a typo question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/186366/225437), [Close all the typo questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/225437), and [Should questions where a problem arose from a typo be closed?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/123741/225437).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - `If we still had the "too localized" option` - Right, we don't! Also, `make sure you're checking the right index variable in your for loops` is a *great* (if simple) answer. And, really, this is a logic error more than a typo (a variable name wasn't misspelled, a wrong (but valid) variable was used).

Comment: @admdrew I'd been assuming that the incorrect variable usage might have arisen from copying and pasting the outer `for` loop header to make the inner one, and that one variable reference didn't get updated.  Nonetheless, there's not much in this question that would help someone with the same problem find this question and resolve their own problem.  There's no real _programming_ problem here; it's just a simple typo, like leaving out a semicolon or a close brace.  An answer like "make sure you're checking the right index in your for loops" isn't great, in my opinion, since it's …

Comment: @admdrew what we _always_ do in this kind of loop. The only time we don't is when we make a simple typo, and these are pretty easy to catch with a debugger. It's not that this isn't a problem that we all run into now and then, or that it doesn't have a definite answer;  it's just not particularly useful to anyone else.  There are very few questions that it would ever make sense to close as being a duplicate of this one (and even if you found one, how you would you find _this_ one again?).  I don't think it's on topic, but fortunately it's a voting system, my opinion alone won't close anything.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor - Ok, good call.

Comment: @admdrew Based on the OP's comments on one of [the answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20227521/1281433), it appears that there was some copying and pasting going on.

Answer (score 4):

Your second for loop has a typo

```
for(int x = 0; i<aOne[i].length;x++){
```

note the **i**

It should be

```
for(int x = 0; x<aOne[i].length;x++){
```

Comment: oh god damnit.  Thank you.  I was going insane -_-

Comment: Actually it's still returning out of bounds >_<

Comment: @ChristopherBaldwin I've tried copying and pasting this code, fixing the typo and for me at least it runs to completion. Are you sure it's exactly the same code

Comment: I need to get some sleep.   Theres a second loop below that i hadn't fixed the error in.  Thank you for your continued help.

Comment: @ChristopherBaldwin It's always the way. Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int x = 0; i<aOne[i].length;x++){
```

Should be:

```
for(int x = 0; x<aOne[i].length;x++){  // NOTE THE x<, not i<
```

Answer (score 0):

You made a typo. Try this:

```
 System.out.println("Please Enter the Size of your arrays");
   int arraysize = in.nextInt();
   //initalize array
   int [][] aOne = new int[arraysize][arraysize];  
   int [][] aTwo = new int[arraysize][arraysize];
   int [][] aSum = new int[arraysize][arraysize];
   // load array 1  
  for (int i = 0; i< aOne.length; i++){
      for(int x = 0; x<aOne[i].length;x++){
          aOne[i][x] = ((int)(Math.random()*15));

      }

  }
```